# Image pulled down over parent div

Tags: html, css, image

I need to have an image pulled down over the borders of it's parent div as to be seen in this picture: http://prntscr.com/dqdavn

Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: I need it go down on the y-axis as to be seen in the given picture.

Comment: use z-index and position css properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a transparent background on your image. Then set a negative bottom margin on your inline image. For the DIV use `display: inline-block`.

I assume your HTML looks like this:

```
<div><img src="img.png" /></div>
```

You should use this CSS:

```
body {background: silver;}
div {background: white; display: inline-block;}
img {margin-bottom: -90px;}
```

See it in action here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRbXKw

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!